# help with dual monitor configuration (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, display, monitor, xrandr

in system settings -> monitor I only have 1 monitor shown (build-in). 
I have 2 external monitors connected, this is my current monitors.xml:

```
<monitors version="1">
  <configuration>
      <clone>no</clone>
      <output name="HDMI-1">
          <vendor>ACI</vendor>
          <product>0x22c1</product>
          <serial>0x01010101</serial>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
          <x>1920</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>yes</primary>
      </output>
      <output name="HDMI-2">
      </output>
      <output name="DP-1">
          <vendor>SAM</vendor>
          <product>0x0b3e</product>
          <serial>0x30333635</serial>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>no</primary>
      </output>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

I get the following error message on xrandr:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00* 
  1920_1080_60 (0x2b5) 173.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock  59.96Hz
```

Note that 77 Hz is not officially supported by the manufacturer of any of my monitors.

The monitors are both working at 1080p_60, but the desktop is mirrored. I want to change it to expand the desktop area.

Also, can I delete the

```
  <output name="HDMI-2">
  </output>
```

part?
My monitor connection is named DP-1, shouldn't it be VGA-1, instead? Don't have DP and physical connection is VGA cable. 
I don't have a xorg.conf file, I deleted monitors.xml and rebooted -> the 77 Hz are still there.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked that your graphics card supports three monitors? How does the output of `xrandr` change if you only connect one external monitor?